# ASP.NET textbox returns empty text in onclick of button inside separate updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm dynamically creating textboxes and buttons in a gridview that correspond with each other by row. The buttons are in their own updatepanel to prevent the textboxes from losing the entered text on postback. The textboxes return empty in the onclick method, but I appear to be finding the correct control using a FindControlRecursive method sourced from this site (has the expected ClientID).

I've tried moving the controls into and out of updatepanels, changing the value of EnableViewState for the textbox, and even some suggestions with javascript.

**ASPX Page:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Orders.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gridViewItems0" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QUANTITY">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtQty0" runat="server" ValidationExpression="\d+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <asp:TextBox Width="40px" ID="txtQty0" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" placeholder="0" MaxLength="3" EnableViewState="true"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panelFood0" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd0" runat="server" Text="Add/Update" OnClick="btnAdd0_Click" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument="" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

**Code behind C#:**

```cs
protected void btnAdd0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btnClicked = (Button)sender;
            char rowID = btnClicked.ClientID[btnClicked.ClientID.Length - 1];
            TextBox txtCurrentQty = (TextBox)FindControlRecursive(this, "txtQty0_" + rowID);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ClientID: " + txtCurrentQty.ClientID);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Text: " + txtCurrentQty.Text);
        }
```

**Master Page**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Orders.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %></title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg py-0 navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand py-0" runat="server" href="~/">
                        <span><img src="Images/sitelogo.png" style="margin-right:5px">Orders</span>
                    </a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTarget">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseTarget" style="padding-bottom:3px">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto py-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link py-0" runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link py-0" runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link py-0" runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Company Name</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I should be getting the entered text from the textbox, but text always returns an empty string even though the text is still there. I'm hoping it's something simple that I just don't fully understand since I'm not an expert at this stuff.

Comment: "The buttons are in their own updatepanel to prevent the textboxes from losing the entered text on postback." That's not what update panels are for. If you dynamically add a textbox then cause a postback, the page returns to its previous state, so you could lose the entered text. Do a search on retaining text on postback with dynamic controls. Lots of info available.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I will update the question to provide more clarity as the textbox itself appears to retain the number entered, but even using a breakpoint I can see that the "Text" property equals "" for the found control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is in your FindControlRecursive method, I was able to post back the respective textbox value on button click with the following button onclick even code.

You can replace your btnAdd0_Click method with this to see if it works:

```
protected void btnAdd0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Button btnClicked = (Button)sender;

  string buttonClientID = btnClicked.ClientID;
  buttonClientID = buttonClientID.Split('_').Last();

  int buttonRowIndex = 0;
  int.TryParse(buttonClientID, out buttonRowIndex);

  GridViewRow row = gridViewItems0.Rows[buttonRowIndex];

  TextBox txtCurrentQty = row.FindControl("txtQty0") as TextBox;

  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ClientID: " + txtCurrentQty.ClientID);
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Text: " + txtCurrentQty.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Rashid.  This does not change my results, but it is making me believe that it may have something to do with this being a Web Form with Master Page.  I'm adding the code for the master page now.

Comment: Were you able to find the text box? or txtCurrentQty is null?

Comment: Yes, the text box is found correctly using both the FindControlRecursive method and when I completely replaced my btnAdd0_Click method with yours.  In output, the "ClientID: " line is the same for both methods.  However, the "Text: " line still comes back as empty.

Comment: I made an edit, try the updated btnAdd0_Click event code.

Comment: -Accidentally deleted a comment-
No change. I am getting the textbox ClientID as MainContent_gridViewItems0_txtQty0_0 but the text is still empty.